# How to get the attributes within a tag within a node with SimpleXML in PHP

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

The XML is,

```
<phoneInfo npa="202" nxx="241" blockId="7" lineType="Landline" latitude="38.899904120193"
     longitude="-77.031636354196" centralOfficeName="WASHINGTON" switch="WASLDCRGDS0"
 nxxType="00" nxxDescription="Regular (Plain Old Telephone Service (POTS))">
<operatingCompany ocn="280E" category="C" categoryDescription="competitive" 
name="YMax Communications Corporation - DC" dba="YMax Communications Corporation" 
commonName="Ymax" type="CLEC" address="223 Sunset Ave" city="Palm Beach" state="FL" zip="33480"
 logoWidth="253" logoHeight="47" >
<rateCenter name="WASHINGTON ZONE 1:Washington DC" code="WSHNGTNZN1" type="suburban zone" 
country="US" countryName="U.S.A." state="DC" stateName="District of Columbia" timeZone="ET" 
timeZoneName="Eastern (UTC -5 hours)" dstRecognized="yes">
<lata code="236" state="DC" stateName="District of Columbia" country="US" countryName="U.S.A."
 location="WASHINGTON DC"/>
<bta code="461" name="Washington DC"/>
<mtas>
<mta code="10" country="US" marketName="Washington-Baltimore"/>
</mtas>
<cbsas>
<cbsa code="47900" csa="548" areaName="Washington-Arlington-Alexandria" areaType="Metropolitan"
state="DC-VA-MD-WV"/>
</cbsas>
<counties>
<county fipsCode="11001" name="District of Columbia" type="District" state="DC" 
stateName="District of Columbia" country="US" countryName="U.S.A." landAreaSquareMiles="61" 
populationIn2006="581530"/>
</counties>
<zipCodes>
<zipCode code="20005"/>
<zipCode code="20002"/>
<zipCode code="20004"/>
<zipCode code="20001"/>
</zipCodes>
</rateCenter>
</phoneInfo>
```

What I am trying to do is get the `<county>` nested within `<counties>` like this =>
    `$county_population = (string) $dataset->phoneInfo->ratecenter->counties->county->attributes()->populationIn2006;`

I want to get the data in the tag `populationIn2006`

How to do this?

Please help! Thanks much appreciated for taking your time looking into this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command is close but is missing the `operatingCompany` node and "ratecenter" is misspelled (needs capital C).

As well the XML you've posted is invalid as it's missing the closing `</operatingCompany>` tag but I am assuming that is a copy/paste error.

```
$county_population = (string) $dataset->phoneInfo->operatingCompany->rateCenter->counties->county->attributes()->populationIn2006;
```

Comment: Thanks for taking your time man, but when used, it gives me an error `Fatal error: Call to a member function attributes() on a non-object` No idea what to do next!

Comment: operatingCompany is a child tag within phoneInfo, thanks for pointing out the spelling mistakes!

Comment: Try adding the `phoneInfo` node back in (`$dataset->phoneInfo->operatingCompany…`).

Comment: Bam! That did it man, thanks, can't imagine a spelling mistake can ruin and eat away your time.